# Esconder elementos de acordo com o tamanho da tela

Tags: css

Alguém sabe alguma função em JavaScript, se caso a tela for *mobile* ele aparece uma opção no menu?

E em *desktop* fica normal, mas sem aparecer a opção e em *mobile* aparece.

```
<li class="drop-left"><a href="">Drop Left</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">How deep?</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: Está a utilizar jQuery?

Comment: Não estou usando jquery, somente css para estilizar meu menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com o `@media` do CSS você consegue isso. JavaScript não é necessário para resolver isso.

Deixei comentários no código CSS abaixo para facilitar a compreensão. O funcionamento é simples: todos os itens do menu com a classe `mobile` só vão aparecer quando a tela for menor que `360px`.

```css
.mobile {
    opacity: 0; /* Esconde no desktop. */
    height: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .mobile {
        opacity: 1; /* Só aparece no mobile. */
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<li class="drop-left"><a href="">Drop Left</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">How deep?</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li class="mobile"><a href="#">Item Mobile</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Abaixo você pode ler mais sobre o `@media` do CSS:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries

---

**Observação:** Nem sempre o `display: block` é o ideal, pois você não pode utilizá-lo por exemplo se o elemento tiver `display: inline`. Nesse caso você deveria fazer `display: none / dispaly: inline` e não `block`.

Veja a imagem para entender melhor essa observação. O elemento `<li>` por padrão tem o `display` definido pelo *user-agent* do Chrome como `display: list-item`, logo, se você colocar o `<li>` com a propriedade `dispaly: block` ele perderá o  `list-style` e fica sem a "bolinha" como você pode perceber na imagem:

[image: Observação]

Answer (score 2):

O senhor pode usar um recurso do CSS3 denominado [`media queries`](https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/).

O funcionamento é simples, veja um exemplo:

```
.menu-toggler {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .menu-toggler {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

O que o código acima faz é simples: por padrão, o elemento que possui a classe `menu-toggler` é escondido. Ele só aparece em dispositivos com telas que tenham um tamanho de, no máximo, `500px`.

Sugiro que leia:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries
- https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/